Xcode - Copy Versioning from Main Target to Services
In Xcode 16.0, I am attempting to copy the value of my CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION and  MARKETING_VERSION in a couple service targets to always be the same as my main project target.
This is because Xcode has recently started rejecting builds (even just local Simulator debug runs) if these values do not match across targets. I tried removing the values completely from the service targets as other answers have suggested, and this allows the app to build, but then I get an error when attempting to install the app to the simulator with the error Invalid placeholder attributes. I would really rather not have to update 6 different values every time I change the version or build code of my app, and would significantly prefer to just add a placeholder in the service targets to automatically use the value from the primary build target. Is there a value I can place in these fields to do that?
